# Iterate though Generic List in C#

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class Item
{
        private int  _rowID;
        private Guid _itemGUID;

        public Item() { }

        public int Rid
        {
            get
            {
                return _rowID;
            }
            set {  }

        }

        public Guid IetmGuid
        {
            get
            {
                return _itemGuid;
            }
            set
            {
                _itemGuid= value;
            }

        }

}
```

The above is my custom object.

I have a list:

```
List<V> myList = someMethod;
```

where V is of type Item, my object.

I want to iterate and get the properties as such

```
foreach(V element in mylist)
{
   Guid test = element.IetmGuid; 
}
```

When I debug and look at the 'element' object I can see all the properties in the 'Quickwatch' but I cannot do element.IetmGuid.

Comment: Why do you have "ItemGuid.set" emtpy? It's look as very bad design.

Comment: What do you mean by cannot do element.letmGuid? What happens?

Comment: The error I get is V does not contain a definition for IetmGuid

Comment: Tcks: The Set is empty as I want to serialize this with read only property but no setters and this seems to work.

Comment: why don't you declare the list as List<Item>?

Comment: Seba: I want to be able to build a list of Items or User objects. Both are populated by stored procs and the base table for each have IetmGuid, yes the typo, so based on run tim I can either do List<Item> or List<User> and hence the choice of List<V> where V is determined at run time for Item/User

Comment: Do you think XMl serialization? But when you have a empty "set", the value will not be set after deserialization.

Answer (score 5):

Are you putting a constraint on the generic type V?  You'll need to tell the runtime that V can be any type that is a subtype of your `Item` type.

```
public class MyGenericClass<V>
  where V : Item  //This is a constraint that requires type V to be an Item (or subtype)
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    List<V> myList = someMethod();

    foreach (V element in myList)
    {
      //This will now work because you've constrained the generic type V
      Guid test = element.IetmGuid;
    }
  }
}
```

Note, it only makes sense to use a generic class in this manner if you need to support multiple kinds of Items (represented by subtypes of Item).

Comment: I did this
public class MygenericClass<V>where V:new()

Comment: That's only requiring that type V have a parameterless constructor.  If you always want to use the generic type V as an Item (or subtype), you should constrain the type as I showed above.

Comment: akmad: Say if I always required that type V have a parameterless constructor. would my approach work?

Comment: @Mat The issues is that you are trying to access the IetmGuid property without specifying the type V has to have such a property.  You're welcome for replying 4 years later :P

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring your list like this:

```
List<Item> myList = someMethod;
```

Comment: +1, I don't see why he's using V when the class is called Item.

Comment: fallen888:I want to be able to build a list of Items or User objects. Both are populated by stored procs and the base table for each have IetmGuid,so based on run tim I can either do List<Item> or List<User> and hence the choice of List<V> where V is determined at run time for Item/User

Comment: But is a user an item or an item a user?  If they share a common interface you can break it out.

Comment: @John, then you'll have to cast and do a null check as suggested in another answer here.  :)

Comment: Yeah, that kind of defeats the purpose of typed lists.  You need to either express some relationship between an "Item" and a "User" in your code (through either inheritance or an interface) or use two separate lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( object element in myList ) {
    Item itm = element as Item;
    if ( null == itm ) { continue; }
    Guid test = itm.ItemGuid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list should be declared like this:

```
List<V> myList = someMethod;
```

Where V is the type item.

and then your iteration was correct:

```
foreach(V element in myList)
{
    Guid test = element.IetmGuid;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I do have it declared as 
List<V> myList = someMethod

The error I get is V does not contain a definition for IetmGuid
I guess I want to determine the property at run time and V is not declared until runtime